# Is the sectioning in method of sections, for truss analysis, arbitrary?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

I was looking through a lot of sources about the method of sections. But the thing that stood out to me was that everyone sections a truss such that at least one of the supports, and therefore at least one support reaction force, appears in the section.

So I am wondering, can we not choose the section arbitrarily?

Do we have to include one of the supports in section? For example, is it allowed to section as I have marked in the figure below? We assume that we already know what 2 of the normal forces are, it doesn't matter specifically wich ones we know, so only 3 unknown normal forces are left in my section. I have ignored external forces on the truss.[image: Sectioning of Truss]

If we are allowed to section arbitrarily, wouldn't the method of joints be a special case of the method of sections, where we are only sectioning about a single node?

Comment: Why are the members BJ, JI and IF drawn so much lighter than all the other members?

Comment: I deleted my original answer and posted a new one that, I believe, better addresses your post. Hope you find it acceptable.

Comment: The members you named appears to be drawn lighter because of the then prevailing lighting and partly beacuse i originally forgot to draw them so i added them hastily. Otherwise all the members are equally arbitrary and there is nothing special about them.

Answer (score 0):

> I was looking through a lot of sources about the method of sections.
> But the thing that stood out to me was that everyone sections a truss
> such that at least one of the supports, and therefore at least one
> support reaction force, appears in the section.

While a section typically includes a reaction force(s), it is not necessarily the case. See the solution to question 2 in the following link.

http://adaptivemap.ma.psu.edu/websites/5_structures/method_of_sections/pdf/MethodOfSections_WorkedExample2.pdf

> So I am wondering, can we not choose the section arbitrarily?

A pointed out in the answer by @Gert you can take any part of the structure, including a single member, and apply Newton's laws to it. However, that doesn't mean you will necessarily be able to determine all the unknown forces using Newton's laws on a single member. That's because, for a planar (2D) structure, you have only three equilibrium equations at your disposal, $\sum F_{x}=0$, $\sum F_{y}=0$, $\sum M=0$, so you can have at most three unknowns. That means you generally do not want more than three cuts for your section, unless they involve zero force members as discussed below. In addition, the part of the structure chosen should give you the most efficient approach to solving for the unknowns.

> Do we have to include one of the supports in section?

Not necessarily, as shown in the first link above.

> For example, is it allowed to section as I have marked in the figure
> below? We assume that we already know what 2 of the normal forces are,
> it doesn't matter specifically which ones we know, so only 3 unknown
> normal forces are left in my section.

Only one of the normal forces (at G) directly relates to your "section", which consists of the single member EF (see comments below).

In any event, if members GH and IH are collinear (which they appear to be), then you will find that member FH is what is called a "zero force member" which makes $N_{FH}=0$. That's because for three members connected by a common joint with two of the members being collinear, the other member has to be a zero force member. See the following link on how to determine zero force members in a truss:https://learnaboutstructures.com/Identifying-Zero-Force-Members. So it is the zero force member FH together with the reaction at G that gives you only three unknowns for member EF. The forces in GH and GF can be determined directly by the reaction at G, since FH is a zero force member.

Also, since your truss appears to be symmetrical, BK on the other side is a zero force member, so member BC has three unknowns, and the forces in AK and AB can be determined directly by the reaction at A.

If you select any of the other members of the truss to be your section, I think you will find that there will be more unknowns than three. This makes the selection of a single member as a "section" of limited value. On the other hand, you can find the force in any of the members by choosing a suitable section consisting of one or more triangular units. It's for that reason you will see that any method of sections problem in any textbook or on any mechanical engineering web site will be comprised of one or more triangular units. If you can find an example to the contrary, I'd like to see it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So in conclusion, we are allowed to section however we want, regardless of the usefulness of our sections. Even though we would normally section in a way that is meaningful for a particular situation, I just wanted to know if there are any restrictions on how we section. This is the information i was seeking, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @na3al Yes, that's why I said "As pointed out in the answer by Gert you can take any part of the structure, including a single member, and apply Newton's laws to it". There is no formal definition of a "section", just what is done in practice. But beware that if you were talk to a structural engineer and refer to the area you circled as an application of the method of sections, the engineer would probably be scratching his or her head.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since the sum of forces of any section of the trust must be zero, the net torque produced is going to be constant, moving from one location to another.

Answer (score -1):

We assume, implicitly, that the whole structure is immobile. Of course that means that **any part** (section) of the structure is also immobile.

So we can isolate **any part** of the structure and apply Newton's Second Law ($\text{N2L}$) it.

Which sections we choose is given by the information we seek to obtain. A sufficient number of sections, analysed with $\text{N2L}$, would give **all the forces** in all the nodes.